# TortoiseSVN getting user set keywords with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, tortoisesvn, com-interface

In Tortoise SVN we have set the keywords:

- "KOPF:ReviewDate" with Value "YYYY-MM-DD".

I have written a macro that reads out keywords with COM-Interface (SubWCRev) shwon here:
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_de/tsvn-subwcrev-com-interface.html

I have not found a possibilty to read out the "KOPF:ReviewDate" value?
Is this possible?